# SQL audit table count on created date and modified date in a single row for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to show date created and date modified in an audit table in one row as a total count. However, I am having problems doing this, could be because it isn't possible with the dates of two fields being involved.

The SQL looks as follows:

```
select 'TableNameAccount', convert(varchar,CreatedDate,112) as Datekey, count(CreatedDate) 
from TableNameAccount
Group by 'TableNameAccount', convert(varchar,CreatedDate,112)
```

The above works greated for CreatedDate, but if I want ModifiedDate to be there as well how would that look like in the SQL without causing issues?

So basically I want the following out as above but also include

```
count(ModifiedDate)
```

and group by that at the end but what do I witht the DateKey for ModifiedDate without obscuring the figures?

Comment: can you post some sample data and the expected output? it is unclear as to what you need.

Comment: `CreatedDate` and `ModifiedDate` are independent so you should group and count them separately.

Comment: Look into UNION

Answer (score 0):

Please try below sql:

```
select 'TableNameAccount', convert(varchar,t.CreatedDate,112) as Datekey, count(t1.ModifiedDate ) 
from TableNameAccount t
INNER JOIN TableNameAccount t1 ON t.createdDate = t1.createdDate
Group by 'TableNameAccount', convert(varchar,t.CreatedDate,112)
```